# How to divide matrix over two lines (matrix too big for page)

Tags: formatting, matrices

I'm writing a math assignment and my matrix is too wide for the page and falls off, even if I switch it to landscape. Any advice as to how I can split the matrix over two lines?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11}(b_{11} + c_{11}) + a_{12}(b_{21} + c_{21}) + ... + a_{1n}(b_{n1} + c_{n1}) 
    & a_{11}(b_{12} + c_{12}) + a_{12}(b_{22} + c_{22}) + ... + a_{1n}(b_{n2} + c_{n2}) 
    & \dots 
    & a_{11}(b_{1k} + c_{1k}) + a_{12}(b_{2k} + c_{2k}) + ... + a_{1n}(b_{nk} + c_{nk}) 
    \\
    a_{21}(b_{11} + c_{11}) + a_{22}(b_{21} + c_{21}) + ... + a_{2n}(b_{n1} + c_{n1}) 
    & a_{21}(b_{12} + c_{12}) + a_{22}(b_{22} + c_{22}) + ... + a_{2n}(b_{n2} + c_{n2}) 
    & \dots 
    & a_{21}(b_{1k} + c_{1k}) + a_{22}(b_{2k} + c_{2k}) + ... + a_{2n}(b_{nk} + c_{nk}) \\ 
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{m1}(b_{11} + c_{11}) + a_{m2}(b_{21} + c_{21}) + ... + a_{mn}(b_{n1} + c_{n1})
    & a_{m1}(b_{12} + c_{12}) + a_{m2}(b_{22} + c_{22}) + ... + a_{mn}(b_{n2} + c_{n2}) 
    & \dots 
    & a_{m1}(b_{1k} + c_{1k}) + a_{m2}(b_{2k} + c_{2k}) + ... + a_{mn}(b_{nk} + c_{nk})    
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please edit your example so it is a complete small document so  people can run it and see the issue (in particular you have given no indication of the page size) not `\dots` make better spacing than `...` (but probably will not help here.

Comment: You can introduce a shortcut `s_{ij}:=b_{ij}+c_{ij}` and populate the matrix with the `s_{ij}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have edited it, so it should be clearer now. I'm using the standard article page size.

Comment: @TikZling Thank you for that suggestion. I think it should already work with your adjustment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^n a_{1i}(b_{i1}+c_{i1}) &
\sum_{i=1}^n a_{1i}(b_{i2}+c_{i2}) &
 \dots &
\sum_{i=1}^n a_{2i}(b_{ik}+c_{ik}) \\

\sum_{i=1}^n a_{2i}(b_{i1}+c_{i1}) &
\sum_{i=1}^n a_{2i}(b_{i2}+c_{i2}) &
 \dots &
\sum_{i=1}^n a_{2i}(b_{ik}+c_{ik}) \\

    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\

\sum_{i=1}^n a_{mi}(b_{i1}+c_{i1}) &
\sum_{i=1}^n a_{mi}(b_{i2}+c_{i2}) &
 \dots &
\sum_{i=1}^n a_{mi}(b_{ik}+c_{ik}) 

\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is also a very neat solution. Thank you for taking the time to help.